# how to validate/check the inserted date to current date

Tags: php

I am new in PHP. I have a table that stores the date.

```
id     nic     date
1      765     2012-04-20
2      654     2012-03-19
3      777     2011-01-08
```

I am using jQuery calendar to insert the date. I have no idea how to validate this date to the current date, so that user cannot enter a date that is less than the current date.

I just want to insert the date that is equal to, or greater than, the current date.

here in my datapicker initialization code

```
var A_TCALCONF = {
    'cssprefix'  : 'tcal',
    'months'     : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    'weekdays'   : ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    'longwdays'  : ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    'yearscroll' : true, // show year scroller
    'weekstart'  : 0, // first day of week: 0-Su or 1-Mo
    'prevyear'   : 'Previous Year',
    'nextyear'   : 'Next Year',
    'prevmonth'  : 'Previous Month',
    'nextmonth'  : 'Next Month',
    'format'     : 'Y-m-d' //'d/m/Y' // 'd-m-Y', Y-m-d', 'l, F jS Y'
};

var A_TCALTOKENS = [
     // A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
    {'t': 'Y', 'r': '19\\d{2}|20\\d{2}', 'p': function (d_date, n_value) { d_date.setFullYear(Number(n_value)); return d_date; }, 'g': function (d_date) { var n_year = d_date.getFullYear(); return n_year; }},
     // Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
    {'t': 'm', 'r': '0?[1-9]|1[0-2]', 'p': function (d_date, n_value) { d_date.setMonth(Number(n_value) - 1); return d_date; }, 'g': function (d_date) { var n_month = d_date.getMonth() + 1; return (n_month < 10 ? '0' : '') + n_month }},
     // A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
    {'t': 'F', 'r': A_TCALCONF.months.join('|'), 'p': function (d_date, s_value) { for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++) if (A_TCALCONF.months[m] == s_value) { d_date.setMonth(m); return d_date; }}, 'g': function (d_date) { return A_TCALCONF.months[d_date.getMonth()]; }},
     // Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
    {'t': 'd', 'r': '0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]', 'p': function (d_date, n_value) { d_date.setDate(Number(n_value)); if (d_date.getDate() != n_value) d_date.setDate(0); return d_date }, 'g': function (d_date) { var n_date = d_date.getDate(); return (n_date < 10 ? '0' : '') + n_date; }},
    // Day of the month without leading zeros
    {'t': 'j', 'r': '0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]', 'p': function (d_date, n_value) { d_date.setDate(Number(n_value)); if (d_date.getDate() != n_value) d_date.setDate(0); return d_date }, 'g': function (d_date) { var n_date = d_date.getDate(); return n_date; }},
     // A full textual representation of the day of the week
    {'t': 'l', 'r': A_TCALCONF.longwdays.join('|'), 'p': function (d_date, s_value) { return d_date }, 'g': function (d_date) { return A_TCALCONF.longwdays[d_date.getDay()]; }},
    // English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters
    {'t': 'S', 'r': 'st|nd|rd|th', 'p': function (d_date, s_value) { return d_date }, 'g': function (d_date) { n_date = d_date.getDate(); if (n_date % 10 == 1 && n_date != 11) return 'st'; if (n_date % 10 == 2 && n_date != 12) return 'nd'; if (n_date % 10 == 3 && n_date != 13) return 'rd'; return 'th'; }}

];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the jquery Calendar past dates so that no need to check at the time of insert.

You can do that at the time of datepicker initialization.

```
var dates = $("#from").datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",   
minDate: new Date()
}
});
```

Comment: i am very new in php and javascript.. could you please tell me where should i write this code :(

Comment: Maham, where you have initialized your datepicker add the minDate: dateToday, parameter in the initialization only

Comment: or share the datepicker initialization code so that i can help you out.

Comment: i have added the datepicker initialization code in my question. please check this code...

Comment: Are you using jQuery DatePicker? Or you have customized the code? You have only two variables here.

Comment: i am using jquery DataPicker. download it and use it . i didnot make any change to this code..

Comment: you do not need to do all this things. Just take the id of the text box in which you want to populate the calendar and apply the above script.

Comment: for example if your text box id is dt then write the following code. <script type='text/javascript'> $("#dt").datepicker({
minDate: new Date()
}
});  </script> and your done

Comment: i just give id to my text box "dt" and add your mentioned script code into header.. `<!-- calendar code starts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar2/tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar2/tcal.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> $('#dt').datepicker({ minDate: new Date() } ); </script>
<!-- calendar code link end-->` it dint work :(